# Definir una BindingList como constante

Tags: c#

Necesito crear una lista de moléculas con propiedades como numero atómico, peso atómico, 
Por un lado tengo un enum asi:

```
public enum Molecules
    {
        [Description("Balance")]
        Balance = 0,
        [Description("(CaO) Calcyum Oxide")]
        CaO = 1,
        [Description("(SiO2) Silicon Oxide")]
        SiO2 = 2,
        [Description("(MgO) Magnesium Oxide")]
        MgO = 3,
        [Description("(Al2O3) Aluminium Oxide")]
        Al2O3 = 4,
        [Description("(FeO) Ferrous Oxide")]
        FeO = 5,
        [Description("(FeO) Manganese Oxide")]
        MnO = 6,
        [Description("(P) Phosphorus")]
        P = 7,
        [Description("(P) Sulphur")]
        S = 8,
        [Description("(F) Fluor")]
        F = 9
```

también una clase

```
public class MoleculeProperties
    {
        public Molecules MoleculeCode { get; set; }        
        public double AtomicWeight { get; set; }
        public double AtomicNumber { get; set; }
        public double OpticalBasicity { get; set; }
        public double NumberOfAnions { get; set; }
    }
```

y un type:

```
internal class IEnumerable<MoleculeProperties>
    {

        public void Add(Molecules MoleculeCode, double AtomicWeight, double AtomicNumber, double OpticalBasicity, double NumberOfAnion)
        {
            Add(MoleculeCode, AtomicWeight, AtomicNumber, OpticalBasicity, NumberOfAnion);
        }
}
```

y ahora la bindingList que quiero que sea tratada como una constante

```
internal static class Constants
    {
        internal static readonly BindingList<MoleculeProperties> MoleculeProperties = new BindingList<MoleculeProperties>
        {
            {Molecules.CaO,102,60,1,3 },
            {Molecules.Al2O3,102,60,0.6,3 },
        };
```

Pero me subraya en rojo los registros de las moléculas y me dice Ninguna sobrecarga para el método add

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Personalmente, no entiendo tu pregunta. Que tiene que ver `BindingList` con una _lista de moleculas_? Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y ampliarla un poco, poniendo ejemplos, y si has intentado algo?

Comment: porque una BindingList<> en lugar de una simple List<> ?

Comment: Para aprovechar el enumerador de moléculas, aunque si con una lista lo arreglo, de momento voy tirando...

Comment: no entiendo lo del `type`, estas seguro que esto `internal class IEnumerable<MoleculeProperties>` esta correcto? no falta el nombre de la class de la cual hereda a IEnumerable<>

Comment: MoleculeProperties es la clase...

Comment: El problema como señala  @LeandroTuttini es que estas creando una nueva clase `IEnumerable<MoleculesProperties>`. Pero no tiene nada que ver con `BindingList`

Comment: Y como podría arreglarlo? yo lo que quiere es poder acceder a esa lista como si accediese a una constante del tipo que sea

Comment: Qué propiedad buscas que tenga la constante? que sea inmutable?, lamentablemente las constantes sólo pueden ser de tipos primitivos

Comment: Primero: En especifico para que quieres utilizar un `BindingList<T>`, Segundo: Esta creando mal tu variable, por eso se queja de: ***Ninguna sobrecarga para el método add***, porque no sabe que tipo de datos le estas pasando. Terecero: deberia de ser mas o menos asi: `internal static readonly BindingList<MoleculeProperties> MoleculeProperties = new BindingList<MoleculeProperties>
 {
  new MoleculeProperties(){MoleculeCode = Molecules.Al2O3,AtomicWeight = 102,AtomicNumber = 60,OpticalBasicity = 0.6,NumberOfAnions = 3}
 };`

Comment: Pero si defino algo en type luego si lo puedo usar como tipo no? Lo he hecho ya con un diccionario así:

Comment: pero ese `internal class IEnumerable<MoleculeProperties>` te compila ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si compila eso, es como si fuese cualquier clase con un nombre extraño

Comment: Lo intento hacer como dice Orlando pero me da este error:
Cannot initialize type '' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Te he puesto una respuesta aunque no estoy muy convencido de que es lo que buscas. No la voy a eliminar porque puede darte una idea de que es lo que estabas haciendo mal, pero yo no creo que fuera por ese camino dado que si no te entiendo mal, el objetivo de todo esto solo es poder inicializar "en linea" la lista

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas creando una nueva clase `IEnumerable<MoleculesProperties>` sin heredar de nada realmente, con lo que `BindingList` no tiene acceso a tu método `Add`. Voy a darte una posible solución.

Primero, creemos un constructor para tu clase `MoleculeProperties`:

```
public MoleculeProperties(Molecules moleculeCode, double atomicWeight, double atomicNumber, double opticalBasicity, double numberOfAnion)
{
    this.MoleculeCode = moleculeCode;
    this.AtomicWeight = atomicWeight;
    this.AtomicNumber = atomicNumber;
    this.OpticalBasicity = opticalBasicity;
    this.NumberOfAnions = numberOfAnion;
}
```

Después, en lugar de tu definición de `internal class IEnumerable<MoleculeProperties>`, crea tu propia clase que herede de `BindingList<MoleculeProperties>`:

```
internal class MiClase : BindingList<MoleculeProperties>
{

    public void Add(Molecules MoleculeCode, double AtomicWeight, double AtomicNumber, double OpticalBasicity, double NumberOfAnion)
    {
        base.Add(new MoleculeProperties( MoleculeCode, AtomicWeight, AtomicNumber, OpticalBasicity, NumberOfAnion));
    }

}
```

Como ves, esta clase hereda de `BindingList<MoleculeProperties>`.

Ahora, es sencillo declarar tu colección:

```
BindingList<MoleculeProperties> MoleculeProperties = new MiClase()
     {
          {Molecules.CaO, 102, 60, 1, 3},
          {Molecules.Al2O3,102,60,0.6,3 },
     };
```

Comment: Vale, tien buena pinta, lo probaré